# How to get a separate header only for the first page?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I cannot seem to figure out how to get one header on the first page and another header on all the rest of the pages. In particular I want to have a picture in the header on the first page, and some text in the header for the rest of the pages.

Here is a pretty scaled down template (from http://www.latextemplates.com/)

https://www.writelatex.com/1626273ymtvpf#/4051907/

If I set e.g. \rhead{MY HEADER} I get this header on all pages including the first page. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is a Minimum Working Example of my problem

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Headers - these apply for every page right now
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{TEST}

\title{Article Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a Minimum Working Example here and ensure that the question you ask here is self-sufficient. It should make sense and be of help to future users even if the websites you link to disappear.

Comment: A few hints: Do *not* use `fancyhdr` along with KOMA. It has it's own package called `scrlayer-scrpage`. If you want to create a titlepage, use the global option `titlepage`.

Comment: There are many things in this template that aren't recommendable with KOMA-script. This makes the template one on my list (of many many) templates that i would never recommend. On the contrary, i would recommend not to use that template.

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to mention a few things, so I know what to look out for? Or what to read more about! Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first page in an article document is set with the pagestyle `plain`. That means no header, but a page number by default. The same applies for your posted minimal example.
Since an article document only has the first page using pagestyle `plain` you can use the optional argument.

You shouldn't use `fancyhdr` with KOMA-script. KOMA comes along with an own very very powerful package called `scrlayer-scrpage`. The syntax is a bit different tough, but you can do much more things.

```
\documentclass[
%DIV=calc,
%paper=a4, fontsize=11pt,%default
twocolumn,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[{\includegraphics[width=3em]{example-grid-100x100pt}}]{TEST}

\title{Article Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Johannes and thanks for the answer and advice regarding fancyhdr. However, in your code the first page does not get a header. In particular, I want the first page to have a header that is different from the rest of the pages. Let me update the first post to clarify this

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wish the KOMA documentation was better, or at least easier to grasp for beginners. For fancyhdr there are so many excellent guides and tutorials.

Comment: The authors english isn't the best. Even the original german documentation is hard to read at times. Little hint: he explains the basics and internal, and then comes a pretty simple example. So hang in there ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Neither should `secsty` be used together with KOMAscript, because it may interfere with the very advance internal commands to format headings.

Comment: @Sveinung The site providing all the templates makes the user believe the templates are good, but not one of them so far (haven't looked at all) are badly designed. Fancy look with a crappy implementation. I added [How to get a separate header only for the first page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/483428) to the original question.

Comment: Do you mean not one so far has been well designed? As it stands, you've said that all those you've checked at least have the merit of not being badly designed!

Comment: @cfr Seems i messed something up. So far, not one was designed good. Thanks for noticing.